# HTML CSS: Two elements in a div with fluid background colour

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a nav bar that needs to display 100% of the screen.

```
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div>
            <img src="./logo.png">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wernerfeuer/bakh5u8a/).

The nav css has width: 100%, and left and right padding of 10%.  The logo floats left and ul floats right.  I want the background colour of the img and the rest of the nav bar to the left in red, and the rest of the nav to the right of the img in black.  I could change the background color of the img to red and the background color of the nav to black, but I cannot change the color to the left of the img.

Comment: can you edit your answer with the applicable CSS, perhaps a snippet or fiddle that we can see what you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues you have is `floats`. With `float` the elements are removed from the normal document flow, this means their parent (in this instance the nav div) will collapse, losing its background color. A common fix for this is the "[clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)", a simpler option is to float the nav container too. You also have to counter the box model which add padding on top of width.

I prefer to tackle this with `inline-block` instead of floats:

```css
.nav {
  padding-right: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}
.nav img {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-left: 10%;
}
.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 78%;
  text-align: right;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {color:#FFF;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <img src="./logo.png">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Browse</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See this article for some [pros and con's of inline block](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/). One of which it white space between elements, this is the reason for the `ul` having a width of 78% instead of 80%

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow:hidden to the .nav.

As @JonP explained, the floated items are taken out of the normal flow, and now have block formatting context. Adding the overflow, makes the parent gain context as well.

You can read about it here: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)